# Outlook Stopped Working, Safe mode and re-install/repair don't resolve

Tags: office365, outlook-2016

Over the last month or so, Outlook 2016 (part of 365) has just outright stopped working. EVERY time I open the program it comes up with the message "Microsoft Outlook has stopped working... A problem caused the program to stop working correctly..." etc. Opening in safe mode produces the same result.

I have tried using the Office 365 repair utility (quick and online aka full) AND completely uninstalling all Office products including deleting any data files and pst files for outlook. After reinstalling and restarting, the issue continues to reoccur. The only thing I haven't done is mess around with the registry.

Here at this [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtH75z725OctjOsZ06N02BfdfzSbrQ) is a list of documents associated with the crash from the Event Viewer, as well as some other potentially pertinent logs.

Any ideas?

Gerneio

P.S. I am not willing to re-install windows to fix this...

Answer (score -1):

1. go to this this folder C:\Users[your username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook
2. Delete all the files you find including the datafiles.
3. Repair microsoft office.
4. relauch outlook and everything will be a-ok.

Comment: Didn't work. Will have a look at this https://windowsreport.com/outlook-only-starts-in-safe-mode/ as disabling Add-Ins and a clean install also didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the [Registry](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4b20d40f-c633-4754-b077-ef65f0d13a13/can-only-open-outlook-in-safe-mode?forum=outlook) is what helped me (Outlook 2013 Professional running on Win 10 Home). The following steps (copied from [social technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4b20d40f-c633-4754-b077-ef65f0d13a13/can-only-open-outlook-in-safe-mode?forum=outlook)) took me 3 minutes.

1. Close Outlook if it is running.
2. Start Registry Editor.
3. Browse to the following registry location:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook
4. Rename the \Outlook part of this key to \Outlook-1.
5. Restart Outlook.

When you restart Outlook, a new \Outlook registry key that has default settings is created in this location.

If I had known I had not wasted 2.5h on the below frequently suggested steps that did not help me:

- [disable Add-ins](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-only-opens-in-safe-mode/05e6ec39-49b4-48e9-83cb-1699747e4f76)
- [disable advance graphics](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-2016-crashing-will-only-open-in-safe-mode/a8bb520d-2763-453e-82bc-80dee5c49704)
- reset resetnavpane
- fresh install of Office
- Add a new mail profile in the control panel
- Use [Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant](https://www.lifewire.com/outlook-wont-open-4177980)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had this issue on my laptop which windows completly died on soon after, so I just haven't messed with it since. If i get working again and i run across the issue, I'll have to try this out. Quite annoying that it could have been this simple, but I figured that would be the case!

Comment: @Garneio your welcome. I wonder where the down vote came from? I only encoutered the problem this week so I realise it's too late for your case. But somebody else might benefit. Microsoft Support pages don't help at all. There is lots of advice around and it's difficult to know what is trustworthy.